# error: pathspec 'temp/versionX' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, git-checkout, filepath

In git, I'm trying to check out versions of a specific repository into a version folder inside of a temp folder, but when I do

```
git checkout master~X C:/file/path/temp/versionX
```

I get the error

```
error: pathspec 'temp/versionX' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What's causing the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm assuming `master~X` is the old revision containing the file(s) you want, and that `C:/file/path/temp/versionX` is where you want to place the old file(s).  Two bits of information are missing:  Which old file(s) (relative to the root of the Git repository) do you want?  What is the path to your Git repository?

Comment: Path to the repo is C:/file/path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git checkout` only operates inside the "working tree".  To do what you want, change Git's idea of what the working tree is.  There are a few different ways to do this:

- option 1:  run from the Git repository

  ```
  cd /path/to/repository
  # git automatically locates the .git directory as usual
  git --work-tree=C:/file/path/temp/versionX checkout master~X
  ```
- option 2:  run from the destination directory

  ```
  cd C:/file/path/temp/versionX
  # if --git-dir is specified, Git assumes the working tree is .
  git --git-dir=/path/to/repository/.git checkout master~X
  ```
- option 3:  run from some other directory

  ```
  cd /some/arbitrary/path
  # need to specify both the path to .git and the destination directory
  git --git-dir=/path/to/repository/.git \
      --work-tree=C:/file/path/temp/versionX \
      checkout master~X
  ```

Comment: The file I'm moving it to is inside the directory I'm working. So say for example I'm working in the file C:/dir/myRepo. The file I'm trying to checkout the files to is C:/dir/myRepo/oldversion/temp/versionX. Do I check out the files the same way you just instructed?

Comment: @SSEMember:  I updated my answer.  Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout can't be used like that. What you want is git-archive(1). For example:

```
ancestor=10
git archive --prefix="version${ancestor}" master~$ancestor |
    tar xvf - -C "C:/file/path/temp"
```

This will export the named commit to a tarball on standard output, which tar will then unpack in the appropriate place. It seems a little cumbersome at first, but it will grow on you.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid archive because it takes *Forever* to unpack everything I'd need to. This work project I'm currently doing is unpacking a couple hundred versions of repos, and in future versions, several thousand. I was hoping to checkout the versions of the repo to a different file inside the git repo, then use a move command to get them outside hoping it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mkdir /file/path/temp/versionX
cd /file/path/temp/versionX
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-path=. checkout master~X
```